# Python 3 and Turkish Character In Debian

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

I have to do a project with turkish content. In my ubuntu machine with python 3.6.5, I haven't any problem with this. But in production server, that is a debian machine with the same python 3.6.2, I have:

```
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with ....
```

When I use `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` as [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html), I have:

```
utf-8 can't decode byte
```

I have searched google and stackoverflow all day. And try all suggestions.
Any advice about this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the file is actually UTF-8 encoded?  And you need to show the actual code that reads the file.

Comment: @TobySpeight it is iso-8859-1 (file -i aa.py). Thanks

Comment: Hang on - you're saying that the Python code is in Latin-1 coding?  Then don't lie to the compiler - you need to write `coding: iso-8859-1`, not `coding: utf-8`.

Comment: @Toby Speight I try the latin-1coding before. The eesult is the same.